# iterate through each row and column in dataframe and perform action on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have a DataFrame as below, I would like to create a new column "Six" such that this column's value is dependent on the value of "Second", "Third", "Forth", "Fifth" column value. If value = 1, then append to the value of the First column, if value = 0, then nothing is done. May I know how to do it?

```
Input : 

    First    Second     Third      Forth      Fifth
0   S1       1          0          0          0
1   S2       1          1          0          0
2   S3       1          1          0          0

Expected output

    First    Second     Third      Forth      Fifth    Six
0   S1       1          1          1          0        S1111
1   S2       1          1          0          0        S211
2   S3       1          1          1          0        S3111
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try this:

```
df['Six'] = df.replace({1:'1', 0:''}).apply(''.join, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    First   Second  Third   Forth   Fifth   Six
0   S1         1       0       0       0    S11
1   S2         1       1       0       0    S211
2   S3         1       1       0       0    S311
```